# How to stop the scrolling of parent scroll view when child scroll view is scrolled in android?

Tags: android, scroll

I know we can use touchlisteners for both scroll view,like

```
parentScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Log.v(TAG, "PARENT TOUCH");

    findViewById(R.id.child_scroll).getParent()
            .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
    return false;
    }
});

childScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Log.v(TAG, "CHILD TOUCH");

    // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of  child view
    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    return false;
    }
});
```

what I am facing is my child scroll view is not the immediate child to the parent scroll view.In this `v.getParent()` is not working and when I touch and try to scroll my child scroll view the whole main scroll is scrolling.

Positions of my scroll views in my layout(views are dynamically created so I need to go with so much layouts)

```
linearLayout
  ParentscrollView(0)
          linearLayout(0)
              relativeLayout(0)
                       TextView(0)
              relativeLayout(1)
                    childScrollView(0)
```

need help..Thanks in advance.!!

Answer (score 8):

Isn't `findViewById()` for parent scroll view id not working?

```
childScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Log.v(TAG, "CHILD TOUCH");

    // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of  child view
    findViewById(parentLayouttId).requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: You said the views are added dynamically. Are those view can be referenced directly from activity? which exception is it? NULLPOINTER? stack trace would be nice to find out!

Comment: 04-21 14:50:37.450: E/AndroidRuntime(29975): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-21 14:50:37.450: E/AndroidRuntime(29975):  at com.tabvey.survey.DropDownView$10.onTouch(DropDownView.java:344)
04-21 14:50:37.450: E/AndroidRuntime(29975):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7701)
04-21 14:50:37.450: E/AndroidRuntime(29975):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2210)